# Connect remotely to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SSIS, how can I connect remotely to my database SQL Server so I can extract data from it. I use to connect to a local server. Do I need to write script (using script component)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need in any SSIS Script Task or Script Component for your objective.

SSIS has **OLEDB Source** in the Data Flow to connect and retrieve data from MS SQL Server.

[OLE DB Source in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ole-db-source-in-ssis/)